# What is the capability of AVRISP and USBASP on ATMega48, 328, 2560?

Tags: flash, debugging, fuses

For use with ATMega 48 (old Arduino?), 328 (UNO, Pro Mini) and 2560 (Mega2560) chips, what is the capability for the AVRISP and USBASP programmers on:

1. Can it read, write fuse?
2. Can it read, write Program Flash?
3. Can it work 3.3 and 5 volts?
4. What workable clock frequency range on the MCU?
5. Can it be used under Arduino ISP to write to board so as to erase the bootloader and use the FULL flash space for big user program (eliminate boot loader saves 0.5 to 8KB space on above Arduino boards)?
6. Can it be used with ATMel factory software development tools (Atmel studio and associated tools) to use MCU on chip hardware based breakpoint (Debug wire, JTag, or other names, as on different MCU)?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that these are getting to get you little capability compared to the Arduino-as-ISP solution - and in some configurations, limited flexibility too.

Comment: #4. Using USBASP on AVR running at 1Mhz doesn't work using the arduino IDE. You can instruct avr-dude to program at lower speeds using the `-B` parameter. I've had no problem using USBASP from the IDE on boards running 8Mhz and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Depends on the specific hardware. See the documentation for the *exact* variant you have.
4. See 3.
5. No. They have their own protocol that you must use instead. They are selectable from the `Programmer` menu in the IDE though. However, you must unprogram the fuse bits outside of the IDE.
6. No. They are low-cost tools meant to be used for programming only. You will need an Atmel-supplied debugger in order to use Atmel Studio's debugging features.